# Error - Python pandas.rpy.comon

Tags: pandas, rpy2, anaconda

There is an error message prompt me when I import pandas.rpy.comon?
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/r_interface.html

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-144-63ebebefea80>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas.rpy.common as com

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\rpy\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .common import importr, r, load_data

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\rpy\common.py", line 14, in <module>
    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from rpy2.robjects.robject import RObjectMixin, RObject

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\robject.py", line 5, in <module>
    rpy2.rinterface.initr()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'initr'
```

Comment: Which version of pandas and rpy2 do you have?

Comment: @joris: initr() has been in `rpy2` since its beginning. There is likely a problem with ケンジ リュスケ's installation.

Comment: This might be related to anaconda. You might want to check with the anaconda people. Otherwise reinstall, try using rpy2's conversion, move to rpy2-2.4.0-Dev...